Certificate .PFX file on a remote desktop not working - adobe acrobat
Recently I was introduced to "Digital Signature".
I have a program on my local computer, (dev) - creating PDFS. and I want to sign them.
So, I installed acrobat, made myself a PFX file and Im using it as such:
var signature = new IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature(@"path\Certificate.pfx", "password")

And, it is working fine, when checked.
Now, I have a remote desktop, Im trying to test it there, so I assumed i'd only have to copy the PFX file and easy..
Apparantly Im kind of stuck, and my logger shows:
 2024-04-09 11:47:59.566 +03:00 [ERR][MaagarTviotController - Post() method] error message: Access is denied.
 2024-04-09 11:47:59.567 +03:00 [ERR][MaagarTviotController - Post() method] stack trace:    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature..ctor(String FilePathToCertificate, String Password)

Im trying to understand whether I should export and import the files respectivly ( depends on my working machine ) but, I cant seem to understand any of it.
Any suggestions?
Or maybe am I doing something which is not meant to be done at all, and there are many other straightforward solutions?
Have a good one ! thanks.
